# Why does water evaporate from curry better when you off the gas then heat again?

Tags: water, curry

When I cook curry I often try to make it dry.  When I try to simmer the water off I notice the water takes time to go and sometimes when i think its done i still see a little water in it.

However I notice that if I make a watery curry, when I reheat it over 2-3 days for a little time the water inside evaporates rapidly.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Maybe the water evaporate normally during those 2, 3 days ?

Comment: I don't  think it's really evaporation, so much as thickening due to starches and fats doing their thing over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquid in the pan actually does evaporate more quickly with boiling; however, you may be pulling more water out of your ingredients for a variety of reasons ie salt or acid is drawing off water. Or ingredients packed together in pan (mushrooms esp get watery packed together)

Surface drying of veg (not immersed )during storage may prevent further water loss when reheating.

Developing a 'skin' can prevent veg and meat from losing moisture.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand this answer 90%.  is it just me or is it not a clear answer?

Comment: I am not sure enough to dare an edit, but I think the point is: when the curry cools down, the ingredients' out layer becomes closed. This means if you keep cooking, your veggies keep loosing water. Allow a cool-down, the water stays in the veggies.